# If the inverse image of a set is open then is the set open?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:M\to N$ be a continuous map between smooth manifolds and suppose that $U\subset N$. If $f^{-1}(U)$ is open then can we conclude that $U$ is open?

Comment: Isn't it the very definition of continuity?

Comment: @AlejandroMenaya No, it's the converse.

Comment: @AlejandroMenaya No. Continuity means $U$ open $\implies f^{-1}(U)$ open.

Comment: My mistake, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, we cannot. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\displaystyle\frac1{1+x^2}.\end{array}$$Then $U=\left(\frac12,1\right]$ is not open, but $f^{-1}(U)=(-1,1)$, which *is* open.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple counterexample:
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto 0.
$$
Then $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\mathbb{R}$ is open, but $\{0\}$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can see why this need not be true in general by noting that what you're asking for is essentially that for your continuous mapping, you're asking whether open subsets of the domain are mapped to open images. But this is *not* required for continuity. Hence it need not hold.